# Merging rows based on duplicate field values using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.6

How do I merge rows with the same values in one of my fields in my attribute table.

I cannot do this manually due to the extent of the duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

[Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool does exactly what you are asking for:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes.

[image]